# A USB drive appears to be unmounting randomly. How do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, unmount

I have a USB drive holding files for a Plex server. The mounted folder is also shared on my home network using Samba.
Nothing has changed recently in either Samba or Plex's config.

Lately, the drive is unmounting itself about once a day while idle and it's taking a manual

```
mount -a
```

to restore it.

Here's the line in my fstab:

```
LABEL=RATHIAN /mnt/RATHIAN auto umask=0000,rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Where do I start looking for a cause or what can I do to make this more robust?